# How to use result in IF to spit out True/False?

Tags: python, pyautogui

The following code snippet

```
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) == "Box(left=200, top=200, width=4, height=4)":
    print("Found")
else:
    print("NotFound")
```

spits out `NotFound`,
but

```
print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)))
```

prints out "Box(left=200, top=200, width=4, height=4)".
How to properly match the result so I can get the Found value back?

Comment: First check `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` returns `str` or not

Comment: Try wrapping the result of `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` in `str()`.

Comment: `if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (968,536,4,4)) == str("Box(left=958, top=536, width=4, height=4"):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("NotFound")`
prints NotFound

Comment: if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path) != None:    print("image found")

Comment: Thank you Milovan! This certainly does work, but for educational purpose i want to know how to deal with Box object return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `locateOnScreen` function returns a `pyscreeze.Box` object, *not* a string.

So you'll want to convert it to a tuple before doing any comparisons:

```py
box = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4))

if box is not None and tuple(box) == (200, 200, 4, 4):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("NotFound")
```

**<Edit>**

The reason you are getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, is because if the image is not found, `locateOnScreen` returns `None`. Trying to convert `None` to a tuple: `tuple(None)` throws an error.

You can protect against this by checking that box isn't `None`, as I've edited above.

I can't explain why you're still getting the error when the image is successfully found however, so you'll need to give some more info for us to solve that.

**</Edit>**

The reason your version doesn't work is because when you call `print(box)`, behind the scenes the `print` function is actually calling `str(box)` and printing that instead.

Thats why even though

```py
>>> print(box)
Box(left=200, top=200, width=4, height=4)
```

it *doesn't* mean that

```py
box == "Box(left=200, top=200, width=4, height=4)"
```

Comment: Still returns NotFound

Comment: It looks to me like the function returns a `Box` object, neither a string nor a tuple.

Comment: Yes, it returns a `Box`, how do i make it work?

Comment: Did you try the trick of wrapping the function call in `str()`?  That will hopefully produce the string value you are comparing against in the cases where you want "Found" to be printed.  Another possible solution would be to compare the result against `Box(left=200, top=200, width=4, height=4)` (without the quotes) so that you are constructing a target `Box` object and then comparing the result to that object.

Comment: i tried `== str("")`, `== Box(x,x,x,x)` (got an error), `== str()`, none worked

Comment: np, just added an explanation as to why your method doesn't work. any questions just ask :)

Comment: Copy paste of your code returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, however `if tuple(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(x,x,x,x))` does work but when object is not found it returns `None` and it prints `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` in console again. I need both values so i can make it Work and Standby in my program.
To clarify: copy paste of your code results in NoneType errors both when image is found and when not. `if tuple(pyautogui.....)...` returns NoneType only when image is not found.

Comment: Take another look at my edit, but you might want to consider getting a little more comfortable with python before trying to use something like this if you weren't able to solve this problem on your own ;)